# IOS version 12.2 and 12.3 UlWebView click video to play not work

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have very old ios application build in objectice C and using Webview to view our site page play the video . The release of 12.2 and 12.3 the Webview don't work properly anymore if you  click video to play not work. 
Bellow IOS 12.2 work fine.

But i have solution on this  by 
adding webView.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction　= FALSE; 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview/1617954-mediaplaybackrequiresuseraction?language=objc

Comment: Step one to modernize this app: abandon UIWebView. It is deprecated. Switch to WKWebView. It is supported and works.

Comment: I too have the same problem, especially with video's on Vimeo. The property you propose as a solution is not entirely working...the video sometimes loads, sometimes it doesn't, and most of the time it takes forever to begin loading